# Как вывести список файлов в JList?

Tags: java, swing

Есть диалоговое окно и на нем компонент JList. Вот его модель:

```
DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
list1.setModel(model);
```

Получаю список файлов

```
File myFolder = new File("/users/derkode/documents");
File[] files = myFolder.listFiles();
```

Как мне теперь вывести этот список в list1?

Comment: А что вам мешает добавить извлечь из каждого файла его имя и добавить в вашу модель?

Comment: Ну собственно я так и сделал:

for (File f : files) {
model.addElement(f.getName());
}

Comment: @derkode: Тогда проблема решена?

Comment: Да - проблема решена.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделайте свою реализацию от AbstractListModel

Comment: Ой, а я это не умею. Непокажите как?

Comment: [derkode][1], точнее на YourModel extends AbstractListModel, то есть **Вашу** реализацию модели


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/users/14935/derkode